# Java SWT - Coloring specific characters in TableItem

Tags: java, user-interface, swt

In my SWT program, I have a table that the user interacts with, upon some form of interaction, I want one of the cells to change slightly depending on that interaction.

The interaction's result should colorize a a correspondent TableItem in the same row, but only in a specific character range.

I know how to set the foreground color for the whole item using setForeground(i, color), but I don't know how to make it more specific.

Is there a way to use StyledText with this? The event is mouse click-based.

Thank you.

Comment: You will need to use [custom drawing](https://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-CustomDrawingTableAndTreeItems/customDraw.htm) for just SWT or `OwnerDrawLabelProvider` if you are using JFace `TableViewer`.

Comment: Thank you for your comment! Unfortunately, this might not be useful for me, I want to do this in other external events like when a user clicks an item.

Comment: So you just redraw the table using different colors when you get the click.

Comment: Thank you, I will try that.